# Determine whether a series is arithmetic or geometric

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Whether the following sequence is arithmetic or geometric 
$7, 7, 7, 7,\ldots$
I think it satisfies both conditions of arithmetic and geometric sequences but if we try to calculate the sum of finite terms of it using the geometric series sum we get 
$$S_n=\frac{7 \cdot 0}{0}$$ which is indeterminate but it is okay with the arithmetic series then it is arithmetic sequence .
Does that correct or not ?

Comment: The geometric series sum works only with a non-constant geometric sequence. What you should see is the definition : is the ratio of consecutive terms the same across the sequence?  If you see, it is clearly both arithmetic and geometric.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify things from definition.

As you said, it satisfy both conditions hence it is both an arithmetic sequence and a geometric sequence.

The formula that you used required us to check the condition of the common ratio is not one.

If the common ratio is $1$, then $S_n = a_0n$.